# The following MariaDB stored procedure doesn't work properly as it updates all the rows in table, not only which meet the WHERE criteria

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, where-clause

The following MariaDB stored procedure doesn't work properly as it updates all the rows in table, not only which meet the WHERE criteria. What's wrong in my code?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spupdatedepartments`(
    IN `DeptID` INT,
    IN `ClinicID` INT,
    IN `DeptName` VARCHAR(250),
    IN `Description` VARCHAR(250),
    IN `Remark` VARCHAR(250)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbdepartments SET ClinicID=ClinicID,DeptName=DeptName,Description=Description,Remark=Remark  WHERE DeptID=DeptID; 
END
```

Comment: Can you try creating simpler tables and making a [mcve] (which in this case would include a simple table that, with the simplified query, exhibits the problem)? Also, you might want to read the [tour] while you're waiting for an answer after you've [edit]ed the question to include the [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET ClinicID=ClinicID
```

That is setting a column to the current value of that column.

```
WHERE  DeptID=DeptID
```

Well, a column is always equal to itself (unless it is `NULL`).

Suggest you make it clear what is coming in versus what is in the table.  Putting a leading underscore on the arguments is one approach:

```
IN `_DeptID` INT,
IN `_ClinicID` INT,
...
SET ClinicID = _ClinicID
...
WHERE  DeptID = _DeptID
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just solved the problem by changing parameter name. It worked properly.